# ProcessPoolExecutor increase performance in non-intuitive way

Tags: python, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing, python-multithreading

I have an application which is basically multithreaded: thread 1 is computation and thread 2 is GUI (Tkinter). One of the parts of the computation includes a function with loop. So I decided to use multiprocessing here in such a way:

```
def mpw1(idw_tree, mapsdata, inlines, xlines, x, y, dfattrs, calcplan, attrsdim, mdim):

    n_cores = os.cpu_count()
    flatcubec2 = np.zeros((attrsdim,mdim))

    with ProcessPoolExecutor(n_cores) as ex:
            args = ((i, calcplan, idw_tree, mapsdata, dfattrs, flatcubec2, inlines, xlines, n_cores) for i in range(n_cores))
            flatcubec2 = ex.map(circle, args)

    return flatcubec2
```

where `circle` is just a computational function (let's say it's counting something).

But what is strange, is that setting `n_cores` as much as possible not allows me to get the best performance. Here is some info:

8 cores (max) - 17 sec
6 cores - 14 sec
4 cores - 12 sec
3 cores - 14 sec
2 cores - 17 sec

What actually is going on? Why does using the maximum of your hardware not allows to get the best performance? Is the problem in my way of using **multithreading**?

Comment: Since you didn't accept the current answer, what sort of answer are you looking for? Are you planning to update your answer with more information? With the information you currently provided I think it's hard to give a more useful answer.

Comment: Sorry for my late answer, but the problem is solved. This behavior is explained by the fact that I used wrong command (multiprocessing.cpu_count()) to set amount of processes to use, this command return me twice more than it should be, in mp it is necessary to use only physical cpu, without logical ...

Comment: Nice to hear you found the solution. Could you post that as an answer? Other users (including me) might be interested in the details. You're even allowed to accept your own answer if you think it's the best answer available. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This behavior is explained by the fact that I used wrong command (multiprocessing.cpu_count()) to set amount of processes to use, this command return me twice more than it should be, in mp it is necessary to use only physical cpu, without logical
So, this behavior, when after 4th "worker" (maximum of physical cpu's in my case) perfomance starts to decrease can be explained by the fact that multiprocessing works explicit and predictable with physical cpu's only. To get amount of physical cpu's only I used :

```
psutil.cpu_count(logical = False)
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, since you're using a `ProcessPoolExecutor`, it's **multiprocessing**, not **multithreading**. Multithreading does offer little to no performance increase in Python due to the Global Interpreter Lock.

Secondly, it's hard to explain the performance of your application without seeing the actual code. Multiprocessing involves quite some overhead, so it's only useful if you've quite some processing work to do (and enough available cores to execute the processes, of course).

From the results you posted it seems that up to 4 cores the workload is divided over the available cores and some performance is gained, but when using more cores the overhead increases up to a point where it is more expensive than the gain in processing time.

Comment: Thank you for response, and yes, You are right, ProcessPoolExecutor refers to multiprocessing, but, as I said before, generally, the code I posted is launching in one global thread (because outside this thread there is one more thread with GUI part which I prefered to hide)
What you mean by "some overhead" and how can it explain why using more cores leads to decreasing in perfomance, since other core gets less loaded ...

Comment: @АндрейСевостьянов, Starting & stopping of a process also takes time (and I'm not sure if you do this in a loop or if each process is started only once and runs for 12-17 s). Also, depending on what data is accessed, cache might work less optimal when multiple cores are using it. There can be many reasons but I really can't answer in more detail without knowing the actual code. Could you create a [mre] and add it to your question? Can you reproduce the issue when executing only the computational thread and leave out the GUI? That would provide useful information to understand the issue.